# org.apache.ignite : Failed to connect to cluster, connection failed and failed to reconnect

Tags: ignite

I am using spark to integrate ignite query data. The program does not start long before the following error occurs. I check the status of ignite, the service node is present.

```html
import org.apache.ignite.spark._
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition
import org.apache.ignite.scalar.scalar
import org.apache.ignite.scalar.scalar._


// val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())
val ic = new IgniteContext(sc,"/data/dk/jar/config/default-config.xml")

 val recordCache = ic.ignite.cache[String, AttendRecord]("ATTEND_RECORD_TL")
    var retSet : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[java.sql.Timestamp] = null
    if(operateTimeSite != null) {
       retSet = recordCache.sql("punchSiteId = ? and operateTime <= ? and operateTime >= ? order by operateTime desc limit 1",punchSiteId, compueteTcTime,operateTimeSite).getAll.map(_.getValue.operateTime) 
    }  else {
       retSet = recordCache.sql("punchSiteId = ? and operateTime <= ?  order by operateTime desc limit 1",punchSiteId, compueteTcTime).getAll.map(_.getValue.operateTime) 
    }
    if(retSet == null || retSet.isEmpty) { 
        if(operateTimeSite !=null) 
            retSet = recordCache.sql("punchSiteId = ? and operateTime >= ?  order by operateTime limit 1",punchSiteId, new Timestamp(operateTimeSite.getTime - 4*3600*1000)).getAll.map(_.getValue.operateTime) 
        else null  
    }
```

```html
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1791)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:978)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1896)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1648)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1076)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:596)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:536)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.getOrStart(Ignition.java:414)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [], reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:300)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:842)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1786)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to connect to cluster, connection failed and failed to reconnect.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$Reconnector.body(ClientImpl.java:1490)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
```

Comment: Could you provide contents of your configuration XML file?

Comment: <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="180000"/>
    <property name="segmentationPolicy" value="RESTART_JVM"/>
    <property name="segmentCheckFrequency" value="180000"/>
    <property name="sqlConnectorConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.SqlConnectorConfiguration"/>
    </property>

Comment: <property name="ipFinder">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
            <property name="addresses">
              <list>
                <value>172.17.112.139:47500..47510</value>
                <value>172.17.112.140:47500..47510</value>
                <value>172.17.112.141:47500..47510</value>
                <value>172.17.112.142:47500..47510</value>
              </list>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>

Answer (score 1):

You use Ignite integration for Spark in standalone mode. It means, that a client Ignite node will be started internally. It will look for other nodes, and connect to them. So, you need Ignite cluster to be running separately and be available by IPs, that you specified in the configuration of `IgniteContext` in its IP finder.

IP finder should contain addresses of server nodes. So there is no need to specify addresses of other Spark executors, that have client nodes internally.

*"Failed to connect to cluster, connection failed and failed to reconnect"* error means, that a client node failed to find any server nodes by the specified IPs.

There is also an embedded mode, with is an alternative to standalone, when a server Ignite node is started instead of a client. This can be enabled by using another constructor of `IgniteContext`:

```scala
val ic = new IgniteContext(sc,"/data/dk/jar/config/default-config.xml", false)
```

But usage of this mode is highly discouraged, and it will be removed very soon. So I would recommend running an Ignite cluster separately.

For more information refer to the following documentation page: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd

**P.S.**

You use a [multicast](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/multicast/TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.html) IP finder, that makes Ignite scan all IP addresses in a configured multicast group. If you know all IP addresses of your server nodes, then you can use [TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder](https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/pe/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/vm/TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder.html). It will let Ignite instances start faster.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tested it and didn't report it wrong.val ic = new IgniteContext(sc,"/data/dk/jar/config/default-config.xml", false)

Comment: @simonqian as I already mentioned, embedded mode is highly not recommended to use, since Spark executors will store data, that will cause excessive rebalancing and possible data loss. I recommend you to start Ignite cluster separately.

Comment: ，I use this configuration: val ic = new IgniteContext(sc,"/data/dk/jar/config/default-config.xml"), create an ignite client, appear Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.NodeStoppingException: Operation has been cancelled (node is stopping).

Comment: I use this method: TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder, which specifies the service node of ignite

Comment: I am running the spark program in zeppelin.

Comment: Looks like this is a different problem. Could you create a separate question and post all details with code and exceptions there?